# Delete specefic element from MongoDB Colection based on ID

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, vue.js, collections

I got a collection in MongoDB called "Members". Each member have first_name, last_name and the autogenerated Object ID. I'm getting the data with ExpressJS and display it with VueJS. This works fine for get and post methods, but I also need a delete method. My question is how do I find that specefic member the user clicks on and wants to delete? Here are my code (simplyfied version)

```
<form action="/delete" method="delete">
 <ul>
      <li v-for="(value, index) in allTeamMembers">
          {{ 'Member: ' + value }}
          <button type="submit">Delete</button>
     </li>
 </ul>
</form>


expressApp.delete('/delete' , function (request, response) {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            let dbo = db.db(dbName);
            let myquery = {first_name: 'Tobias'};
            dbo.collection("Members").deleteOne(myquery, function (err, obj) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("1 document deleted");
                db.close();
            });
        });
    });
```

This of course my query viable which needs to change, but I can't find a way to query the clicked element from the list. Right now, it just deletes all with first_name = "Tobias", but I want it to delete the clicked element from the list.

Comment: First, you have to pass user data to the backend. Next, have to get the passed data in your controller like request.body or request.query. In the end, you can delete your document easily as @charlieb mentioned.

Comment: My list consist of "get" data from the db allready, and I have the ObjectID aswell. But I cant find a way to get the Object id when I click the button next to it.

Comment: Then you have to remove mongodb tag and search in vue.js :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, if you are querying to find Tobias, it will find all examples of Tobias.
Perhaps you should store the mongoDB ID as an attribute in the elements, so you can easily access it when it is clicked.
Then you could try and delete based on the unique ID by following this first example: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/#examples

Comment: Thank you for the tip. So I will try that. And you are completely right, my problem is to retrive the ID, so good be a way. I have made some minor changes and updated the code example as well.